# Scikit-learn's fetch does not download dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, scikit-learn

From iPython, I executed

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_olivetti_faces
```

The command seem to execute immediately with `In [43]` appearing infront of the command.

However I do not find anything in the location given by `get_home_data()`, neither can I do

```
data = fetch_olivetti_faces()
```

**Error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-6a7f4fc09c38> in <module>()
      1 # fetch the faces data
----> 2 data = fetch_olivetti_faces()

C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\olivetti_faces.py in fetch_olivetti_faces(data_home, shuffle, random_state, download_if_missing)
     87               % (DATA_URL, data_home)))
     88         fhandle = urllib.request.urlopen(DATA_URL)
---> 89         buf = StringIO(fhandle.read())
     90         mfile = loadmat(buf)
     91         faces = mfile['faces'].T.copy()

TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

downloading Olivetti faces from http://cs.nyu.edu/~roweis/data/olivettifaces.mat to C:\Users\me\scikit_learn_data
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a recently fixed bug in scikit-learn: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/a344f1054095c425236c1be50cf6eb23dc74eb40